# Django Dropdown GET Option Data

Tags: python, html, jquery, django, django-forms

I wanted to get the selected text from the dropdown, But I am getting value if I use `request.GET['Type']`. I wanted to
get `Data001` instead of `Value001`

```js
def index(request):
    print("The output: ",request.POST.get('Type'))
    return render(request,'index.html',content)
```

```html
<div class="form-row last">
    <div class="form-wrapper">
        <label for="">Meeting Type</label>
        <select id="Type" name="Type" class='form-control'>
            <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
            <option value='Value001'>Data001</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-wrapper">
    <button data-text="Book" type="submit" name="action" value="book">
        <span>Book</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Please note that, There are 30+ dropdown options and I must use values in the dropdown. Kindly help me to get the selected option instead on value

Comment: Put "Data001" as the value? `value='Data001'`? Only the name and the value pair of the input fields are submitted to the server the display value is not submitted.

Comment: This is just an example code, I need to get the selected option from the dropdown,
I use value to filter the option. So in the output I need to get what user is selected.

Answer (score 0):

So if this is using for filter purposes and you cannot change the values inside of `option` tags.
Then you can use `AJAX`, you can get the .innerHTML of the selected option, and pass that as a `dict` to your `views.py` function

> views.py

```
def ajax_option(request):
    print("The output: ",request.POST.get('Type'))
    return render(request,'ajax_option.html')
```

> urls.py

```
path('ajax_option/', views.ajax_option, name="ajax_option"),
```

> .html

```
<div class="form-row last">
        <div class="form-wrapper">
            <label for="">Meeting Type</label>
            <select name="Type" class='form-control' onchange="onchangehit(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)">
                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
                <option value='Value001'>Data001</option>
                <option value='Value002'>Data002</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-wrapper">
        <button data-text="Book" type="submit" name="action" value="book">
            <span>Book</span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

> AJAX, right above the body tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function onchangehit(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{% url 'ajax_option' %}",
                    async: true,
                    data: {
                        Type: data,
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                    },
                    success: function () {},
                    failure: function () {}
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: I never used ```AJAX``` , Can you support how to do that in code?

Comment: yeah Sure, I can.

Comment: Thank you so much, please provide me the code.

Comment: Can you please tell me whether I need to pass the .html code in ajax_option.html ?

Comment: you can use the code in your own custom .html files.

Comment: Code is working, But it's displaying the output, the moment I select the dropdown,
Is it possible to get the selected data once I press submit button?

Comment: Yes, it's already there, the form is already submitting and redirecting to the `views.py` file with the selected `Type` value.

Answer (score 0):

add a new input tag with hidden type.
add onchange listener on select of id "Type"
in callback function of event listener, replace the input tag value with the inner text of changed value in select

by this way, you can use it without ajax a

Comment: If possible, Could you please share me the code for better understanding?